# How to not overwrite an app when running on an iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, version, overwrite

I'm making a project and I want to show three different versions of the same one, but when I run one of them, it overwrites the previous one.
I want to have all three at the same time, how can I do it?
I tried to change the bundle display name but it still overwrites it.

Comment: Have you tried changing the bundle identifier (not display name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Bundle Identifier.  You won't be able to change the Product Name, but you can append it with a .1 or something[image: Identifier]